# Добавить элемент в последнюю позицию в ArrayList<Image>

Tags: android, arraylist, gridview

Есть GridView. Необходимо реализовать [данную](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373431/gridview-with-button-to-add-photo) задачу. В ответах указано, что в массив последним пунктом нужно добавить один элемент и далее его проверить в адаптере.

Я пробовал добавлять элемент из drawable, но отображается ошибка (см.скрин).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как добавить один элемент последним в массив типа `ArrayList<Image>`? Возможно этот элемент может быть вообще пустым, главное, чтобы он добавился.

Мой код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
    private ArrayList<Image> imagesAll = new ArrayList<>();
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
        imagesAll = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);

        // тут я пытаюсь добавить один элемент в массив
        Bitmap Icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_done_white);
        imagesAll.add(Icon);

        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imagesAll);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    private class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Image>
        {
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        Context context;
        ArrayList<Image> objects;

        private ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Image> objects)
            {
            super(context, R.layout.gallery_content_image, objects);
            this.context = context;
            this.objects = objects;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
            {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null)
                {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_content_image, parent, false);

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                int x = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_size);
                int y = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_size);
                Glide.with(context).load(objects.get(position).path).override(x, y).centerCrop().crossFade(400).into(imageView);
                }
            return view;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если списку и адаптеру задан тип `<Image>`. Объекты каких классов можно в них добавлять?

Comment: @woesss, если честно, то я очень неопытен. Поэтому затрудняюсь вам ответить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коллекцию можно положить только объект указанного в параметре `<...>` типа или его потомка. То есть как-то так:

```
    Image image = new Image();
    imagesAll.add(image);
```

Ну и в адаптере нужно проверять, что элемент последний, что бы глайду скормить ресурс вместо `Image.path`

**UPD** Вашу задачу можно решить по-другому:
 переопределяем метод в адаптере:

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount() + 1;
    }
```

в `getView` добавляем проверку:

```
        if (position == getCount() - 1) {
              // это последняя ячейка
        } else {
              // а здесь все из списка
        }
```

Comment: Подскажите, чтобы можно было добавить в `new Image();`? Сейчас красным подсвечиваются скобки ().

Comment: Я же не знаю что это за класс и где Вы его взяли. Смотрите по подсказкам, документации или сорцам, если есть.

Comment: @Gamlet, добавил другое решение без "пустышки"

Comment: Спасибо большое )) этот вариант помог ))